# Fatal Exception Route::get does not work Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I´m trying to get the date from an user in my DDBB, them, I have 2 customer in a table.

The schema is called - customers
The table is called - names

And names has two columns, id and name, its very simple. I have added two persons in my table, Tony and Bob.

In laravel, in the app folder, I have created a new php file, and I put this:

```
<?php

namespace App; 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model{

}
```

And I have this code in my .env file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=customers
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Then, I just want get my first customer, Tony, and in routes.php I have write this:

```
Route::get('customer', function(){
    $customer = App\Customer::find(1); 
    print_r($customer); 
});
```

When I run the application, I get this message:

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 23:
Class 'App\Customer' not found
```

I would like to get something, but I don´t know what happen. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'use App\Customer;' on top of your routes file?

Comment: Have you tried '\App\Customer'? (Use a backslash before 'App') This is clearly a name spacing issue, and your Model appears to be set up correctly, so '\App\Customer' in routes.php should work.

Comment: Sorry I could´t read it, I did´t tried. I going to try. Thanks =).

Comment: I have tried adding: use \App\Customer and use App\Customer on the top of my routes.php, before and after <?php line, this is my first time with laravel and I cant imagine ways to resolve this :S

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer = new Customer;
$customer->name = $request->name;
$customer->mobile_number = $request->mobile_number;
$customer->mail = $request->mail;



$request->name.......this name and $request->Mobile_number,$request->mail is .... form field name.
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

It says - Class 'App\Customer' not found.

Seems your class Customer is not loaded. Make sure, your Customer model is in App folder. Also the file name must be Customer.php. Also the class name must start with C(Capital) - Customer. And also make sure, you have defined the namespace as follows in Customer model.

```
namespace App;
```

Example

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customer';
}
```

And try like this and see ?

```
Route::get('customer', function(){
    $customer = \App\Customer::find(1); 
    print_r($customer); 
});
```